# Is there are a way to read images into a prediction engine without saving to file first?

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

All the of the Microsoft tutorials on ML.NET involve reading images from a file and referencing them only using their file location. I'm trying to implement a prediction engine into piece of code which is taking photos as it is being run. Currently I'm saving all my images to file and then reading them to make a prediction but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: What is the API documentation for ML.NET saying? Look at the type that offers the file load method you are currently using. Chances are it also offers other load methods for loading data from a stream or similar...

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3839) it's in their backlog :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was enabled in MAdded support for in-memory ‘image type’ in IDataview was enabled in ML.NET 1.1. Please read this blog post for more details https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ml-net-1-1-and-model-builder-updates-machine-learning-for-net/

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8) in place of a [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8) anywhere a file is needed

Comment: it's a comment ?